# UITableViewCell subclasses not behaving like UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My function takes in a function of type `(cell: UITableViewCell, item: AnyObject) -> ()` as a parameter.

My problem is that when I try to pass a function that has a *subclass* of `UITableViewCell` as a parameter, I get the error:

`Cannot convert value of type '(tableCellSubclass, post: Post) -> ()' to expected argument type '(cell: UITableViewCell, item: AnyObject) -> ()'`

How can I change the function with type `(cell: UITableViewCell, item: AnyObject) -> ()` so that functions using subclasses of `UITableViewCell` conform to it?

Here are the relevant code snippets. The first is ArrayDataSource which I am trying to instantiate.

```
class ArrayDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    let items: [AnyObject]
    let cellIdentifier: String
    let configureCellBlock: (cell: UITableViewCell, item: AnyObject) -> ()

    init(items: [AnyObject], cellIdentifier: String, configureCellBlock: (cell: UITableViewCell, item: AnyObject) -> ()) {
        self.items = items
        self.cellIdentifier = cellIdentifier
        self.configureCellBlock = configureCellBlock
        super.init()
    }

    func itemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> AnyObject {
        return items[indexPath.row]
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let item = self.itemAtIndexPath(indexPath)

        configureCellBlock(cell: cell, item: item)
        return cell
    }
}
```

This is where I am instantiating ArrayDataSource from, and where I am getting my error.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        // ...

        let postsArrayDataSource = ArrayDataSource(items: posts, cellIdentifier: "tableCell", configureCellBlock: configurePostTableViewCell)

        // ...
}
```

Finally, this is the function I want to pass as a parameter.

```
func configurePostTableViewCell(cell: postTableCell, post: Post) {
        //sets up formatted string for last confirmed
        let lastConfirmed = dateSimplifier(post.confirmed)
        var boldLastConfirmed = NSMutableAttributedString()
        boldLastConfirmed = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "last confirmed: \(lastConfirmed)", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Italic", size: 15.0)!])
        boldLastConfirmed.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic", size: 15.0)!, range: NSRange(location: 16, length: lastConfirmed.characters.count))

        //sets up formatted string for posted date
        let posted = dateSimplifier(post.posted)
        var boldPosted = NSMutableAttributedString()
        boldPosted = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "posted: \(posted)", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Italic", size: 15.0)!])
        boldPosted.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic", size: 15.0)!, range: NSRange(location: 8, length: posted.characters.count))

        //sets up formatted string for title & type
        let title = post.title
        let type = post.type
        var boldTitle = NSMutableAttributedString()
        boldTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(title)  \(type)", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 18.0)!])
        boldTitle.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "BodoniSvtyTwoSCITCTT-Book", size: 18.0)!, range: NSRange(location: title.characters.count + 2, length: type.characters.count))
        if (type == "free") {
            boldTitle.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0), range: NSRange(location: title.characters.count + 2, length: type.characters.count))
        } else if (type == "cheap") {
            boldTitle.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.75, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0), range: NSRange(location: title.characters.count + 2, length: type.characters.count))
        }

        //sets values for strings in cells
        cell.titleLabel.attributedText = boldTitle
        cell.lastConfirmedLabel.attributedText = boldLastConfirmed
        cell.postedLabel.attributedText = boldPosted

        //sets image based on post's status
        switch post.status {
        case 0:
            cell.statusImage.image = UIImage(named: "Help Filled-50.png")
        case 1:
            cell.statusImage.image = UIImage(named: "Good Quality Filled-50.png")
        case 2:
            cell.statusImage.image = UIImage(named: "Poor Quality Filled-50.png")
        case 3:
            cell.statusImage.image = UIImage(named: "Help Filled-50.png")
        default:
            NSLog("Unknown status code for post.")
        }
  }
```

Comment: Why the tag `osx`?

Comment: @NicolasMiari I'm having the same issue with table view cells in developing an OSX app.

Comment: Did you try using `as?`?

Comment: @NicolasMiari How exactly?

Comment: Can you post more of your code?

Comment: Can you just cast the subClass of UITableview to UITableview?

Comment: I added more code. @tennis779 Where would I do that?

Comment: Seems like a good use case for generics, but I've been lazy w/Swift lately & don't recall the specifics. Couldn't you, instead of explicitly requiring a `UITableViewCell` instead use a generic that either is a `UITableViewCell` or requires conforming to a protocol that would allow your subclass? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use generics to achieve this. Create a generic `ArrayDataSource`:

```
class ArrayDataSource<T: UITableViewCell, U: AnyObject> : NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    let items: [U]
    let cellIdentifier: String
    let configureCellBlock: (cell: T, item: U) -> ()

    init(items: [U], cellIdentifier: String, configureCellBlock: (cell: T, item: U) -> ()) {
        self.items = items
        self.cellIdentifier = cellIdentifier
        self.configureCellBlock = configureCellBlock
        super.init()
    }

    func itemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> U {
        return items[indexPath.row]
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("identifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! T
        let item = self.itemAtIndexPath(indexPath)

        configureCellBlock(cell: cell, item: item)

        return cell
    }
}
```

Create one specific to your cell and item like this:

```
let postArrayDataSource = ArrayDataSource<postTableCell, Post>(items: posts, cellIdentifier: "tableCell", configureCellBlock: configurePostTableViewCell)
```